# "That's part of the deal" meaning

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj3Fc.jpg)]

In this quote from the picture, what does the word "part of the deal" mean?
I assume it means "the time  when the devil gives out cards to us in a life game"

Answer (score 2):

> the deal

can be thought of as the underlying, if assumed, "contract" one accepts when doing something.

Part of one's "deal" with an employer would be "services for pay", you perform a service, you expect your employer to pay your for those services.  Likewise, your employer expects you to perform to the best of your ability and to show up for work.

> It's part of the deal.

is an idiom which often gets used when an undesirable condition exists which could have been understood to be a preexisting requirement.

For example, parents often suffer from sleep deprivation with a newborn, however that's  "part of the deal" of having a newborn.

In a way you are right in your understanding that we can only use the cards we have been dealt, "the deal" in card play.

What Leonardo is saying is that hard times should be expected, nothing is always smooth sailing, generally it's part of the "deal" of being alive.